# Proof verification: Showing, through Induction, that a set $S=\mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, solution-verification, integers

> Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ where: (i) $2^k\in S$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$; and (ii) for all $k\ge 2$, if $k\in S$, then $k-1\in S$. Prove using induction that $S=\mathbb{N}$.

So the base case:  If $k=1$, then by (i) $2^1=2\in S$. Then by (ii), $1\in S$.

Now the assumption, $k\le n$.  So we assume that for all $k\le n$ that through (i) we have $2^k\in S$.  But now that we know that by (ii) $2^k\in S$, so therefore $2^k-1, 2^k-2,...,2^{k-1}+1$ are all in $S$.  (Seems like a kind of reverse induction?...)  So now I think all integers up to $2^k$ are assumed to be in $S$

So finally, for $2^{k+1}$, we have that $2^{k+1}\in S$.  But since $2^{k+1}\in S$, so is $2^{k+1}-1$ by (ii) and thus so is $2^{k+1}-2, 2^{k+1}-3,...,2^{k+1}-(2^k-1)$.  This last value is nothing more than

$$2^{k+1}-(2^k-1)=2^{k+1}-2^k+1=2^{k}(2-1)+1=2^k+1$$

And since we know $2^k\in S$ then every integer in between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}$ is now also in $S$.  Thus, for all natural numbers $k$, all integers are in $S$ which means finally that $S=\mathbb{N}$.

I've never done an induction proof like this before, so I was challenging myself to understand the logic of why it to be true and I think I succeeded, but there's a nagging feeling that I'm not using my assumptions in the correct manner, so I'm thinking that this line of reasoning and logic is wrong. Can anyone please take a look and see if I'm right or my logic is faulty?

Comment: in the base case, you say that by (i) $2^1 = 2 \in S$, but by the (i), you can only afirm that if $1 \in S$

Comment: I'm not getting what your saying.  Since by (i), 2 is now in the set, then by (ii), since 2 is now in S, 1 must also now be in S.  That's how I read it.

Comment: @Ulivai, I think I made a mistake.  I changed the condition.  it should have read (i) $2^k\in S$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, not S.

Comment: So by (i), we have that all powers of $2$ are in $S$ except $1$, since $2^0=1$, but $0\notin\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: right! indeed my problem was with  the statemant "for all $k \in S$"

Comment: +1 I think the title was pretty good! I added “Proof verification” (because it reflects that you did put in the work, nice job) and the [tag:proof-verification] which displays [tag:solution-verification] as a synonym instead for some reason.

Comment: @Deepak, its a problem from Bartle & Sherbert's Introducition to Real Analysis.  The exact problem verbatim is:  Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that (a) $2^k\in S$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, and (b) if $k\in S$ and $k\ge 2$, then $k-1\in S$.  Prove that $S=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish, I saw that... I was trying to make it specific so as to follow the rules of the site.  With a million problems, I'm sure there's a lot of very bland and general titles that don't necessarily reflect the exact problem.  Thank you.

Comment: In the base case, you say: “Then by (ii), $1\in S$.” Unfortunately, (ii) only applies if $k\ge2$, which $1$ is not.

Comment: @Mando I deleted my comment because it was based on your original question text stating $k \in S$ which you had not corrected. The problem with that condition is that you're not actually guaranteed a base case to induce from. You must have a stipulation that at least one natural number greater than or equal to $2$ belongs to $S$, in which case the question is doable even with the condition written as $k\in S$.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish,yeah  I see what you are saying.  I thought this was easier and now I'm confused as to how to proceed.

Comment: @Mando Your base case should actually be $2$. Applying (ii) to $k=2$ will reveal that $1\in S$. Pretty sneaky, huh....

Comment: So for $k=1$, by (i), $2\in S$.  But since $k<2$, we have that $S=\{2\}$.  For $k=2$, $4\in S$, and now, since $k\ge 2$, then $1\in S$ and $S=\{1, 2, 4\}$..

Comment: Then for $k=3$, we have that $S=\{1, 2, 4, 8\}$, $k=4$ we have $S=\{1,2,3,4,8,16\}$... is that the gist of it?

Comment: You’ve done good work! But you’re overcomplicating it. Allow me to take out the unnecessary steps. **Base case** in two parts: For $k=1$, by (i), $2\in S$. By (ii), $2-1=1\in S$. I’ll turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the base case, you say: “Then by (ii), $1\in S$.” Unfortunately, (ii) only applies to $k\ge2$.

The base case should actually be **two** steps, as follows. Take $k_{\rm (i)}=1$, so (i) guarantees $2\in S$. Now take $k_{\rm (ii)}=2$, so (ii) guarantees $2-1=1\in S$.

Now proceed! You have a good handle on how induction works; the rest is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Step back and ask..... what's going on?

For any $n\in \mathbb N$ we can find $k$ so that $2^k \ge n$.  And $2^k \in S$ so because $n \le 2^k$ then $n\in S$.  So every $n\in N$. And so $\mathbb N \subset S \subset \mathbb N$ so $S = \mathbb N$.

Sure that seems simple enough.

But we must prove two things:

1) For any $n\in \mathbb N$ we can find $k$ so that $2^k \ge n$

2) If $k\in S$ and $n\le k$ then $n \in S$.

I'd actually do this in two separate proofs.

And for each proof be induction the key will be forming the statement.

Proof 1:  $P(n):=$ for any $n$ there is a $k$ so that $2^k \ge n$.

Base case:  $n = 1$ if $n=1$ then $k=1$ and $1 < 2^1$.

Induction step:  $n=m$, assume there is some $k_m$ so that $m \le 2^{k_m}$.

If $m < 2^{k_m}$ then $m + 1 \le 2^{k_m}$.

(That's clear, right?  If $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ then $a < b\implies a+1 \le b$.... we don't need to prove that do we?  We can... $b-a \in \mathbb Z$ and $b-a> 0$ so $b-a\ge 1$ so $a+1 \le b$.)

And if $m = 2^{k_m} \ge 1$ then $m+1 \le m + m = 2m =2*2^{k_m}=2^{k_m + 1}$.

That's it.  Proof 1: is done.

Proof 2:  You noted you did a sort of "backwards induction".  But note, if you make your $Q(n)$ statement right is is a forward induction.

Fix $k$ as a constant so that $k\in S$.

$Q(n):= $ $k-n\in S$ for all $n= 0,......, k$.

Base case:  $n=0$;  Then $k - 0=k-1\in S$.

Induction step:  $n=m$ and assume $k-m \in S$.  If $k-m \ge 2$ then $k-(m+1) = (k-m)-1 \in S$.  And if $k-m< 2$ but $k-m \in \mathbb N$ then $m = k-1$ and we've gone as for as we need.

......

By the way.....

The is a property *very* similar to a "backwards proof by induction using contradiction" using the well ordered principal of natural number.

WOP:  Every non-empty subset of natural numbers has a least,first element.

So if you are ask to prove $P(n)$ is true for all natural $n$ you can do this:

Show $P(1)$ is true.

Consider the set of all natural numbers where $P(n)$ is *FALSE*.  Assume it is not empty.

Let $k$ be the *least* element; that is $k$ is first case where $P(k)$ is false.

Prove $P(k)$ is false $\implies P(k-1)$ is false.

But that's a contradiction because $k$ was the first such number so $P(k-1)$ *can't* be false.

So the set of natural numbers where $P(n)$ is false is empty.

So $P(n)$ is always true.

.....

If if $P(n)$ is $n \in S$. then

Well $2^1 \in S$ so $2-1= 1$ is in $S$ so $P(1)$ is true.

Let $m$ be the first natural number where $m \ne \in S$.

Then $m = (m+1)-1$ so $m+1\in  S\implies m\in S$.  So $m+1\not\in S$.  And  so by induction for all $k > m$ then $k \not\in S$.

Now $2^m > m$. So $2^m\not \in S$.  But that's a contradiction.

SO there is no natural number not in $S$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This is good.  I am unpacking it a bit for the minutiae but I follow the logic.

Comment: I awarded the answer to someone else, not because I thoughtyou were wrong but because the person was helping me throughout the comment thread. I appreciate all of your proofs and help because it definitelty helped me understand the problem as a whole, not just to fix my understanding/misunderstanding.  Thank you so much.

Comment: What is “backwards proof by induction using contradiction”?

Comment: "What is “backwards proof by induction using contradiction”?"  It's proof by induction that goes backward and uses a contradiction, much as that example does.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a subset of $\Bbb N$ with the following properties:

- There exists some $t_0\in T$ with $t_0>1$
- If $t\in T$, then there exists $m\in \Bbb N$ with $t+m\in T$

**Example.** The set of powers of two has this property: Just let $t_0=2$, and for $t=2^k\in T$, we can let $m=t$ and have $m+t=2t=2^{k+1}\in T$.

Let $S$ be a subset of $\Bbb N$ with $T\subseteq N$ and if $s\in S$ with $s>1$ then $s-1\in S$.

**Lemma 1.**
$\forall k\in\Bbb N\colon \forall n\in\Bbb N\colon n+k\in T\to n\in S.$

*Proof.* [Induction on $k$]
For $k=1$, $n+1\in T\subseteq S$ implies $n\in S$, as desired.

For $k>1$, $k=1+k'$, assume $$\tag1\forall n\in\Bbb N\colon n
+k'\in T\to n\in S.$$
Let $n\in \Bbb N$ with $n+k\in T$. Then $n+k=(n+1)+k'$, so by $(1)$, $n+1\in S$ and hence also $n\in S$. Hence $\forall n\colon n+k\in T\to n\in S$.

Now the lemma follows by induction. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** 
$ \forall n\in\Bbb N\colon \exists k\in\Bbb N\colon n+k\in T.$

*Proof.* For $n=1$ we can take $k=t_0-1$.

Let $n>1$ and assume $\exists k\in\Bbb N\colon n+k\in T$, say $n+k=t\in T$. 
If $k>1$, then $(n+1)+(k-1)=t$ and we are done.
If $k=1$, then there exists $m\in\Bbb N$ with $t+m\in T$. 
At any rate, $\exists k\in\Bbb N\colon (n+1)+k\in T$.

Now the lemma follows by induction.$\square$

**Corollary.** $S=\Bbb N$. $\square$